# "it would've had to have really lived for it to have died." what does this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I cannot understand the following sentence on this content. Please help...

> "it would've had to have really lived for it to have died."

What Do I Do If I'm Newly Single? I Just Between Us
https://youtu.be/tSxcAz9Udm8

I guess that this is kind of a joke, but I cannot get it at all...

Below is the transcript from YouTube.

Allison: Think I should get a haircut? 
Gaby: Like a trim?
Allison: No, like I'm thinking I would chop it all off at home.
Gaby: With- with what?
Allison: Like a razor blade.
Allison: This week's question should apply to everyone! How do you handle being newly single in Los Angeles uh, from Allison in Los Angeles.
Gaby: That's just you.
Allison: Could be another Allison who recently had her heart broken.
Gaby: Mm, I don't think it is. You're literally wearing black like you're at a funeral for your love life.
Allison: Well, **it would've had to have really lived for it to have died**, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a nice joke.

> It (=love) would have had to have really lived

It's an example of [the third conditional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if) which is used to describe events that never happened. Allison is saying she was never in love, she didn't experience (true) love in her life.

> for it (=love) to have died

is similar to *for it to die* but with [the perfect infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked) (to have died). It's needed because she is still in the context of an unrealistic situation (her being in love). She basically meant "something that never existed can't die".

Comment: It is really helpful. I understand this is an example of the third condition. Then, I have an additional question. Why does Allison use 
- would "had to" have really lived 
instead of 
- would have really lived?

I don't understand why "had to" is used.

Comment: @KenjiKajiwara it's just a word choice I think, "needed to" would be similar to "had to"

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Alison is referring to her *love life* as if it were a person.

She is saying she isn't in mourning, because her *love life* never actually lived. If it didn't live, it can't die, so her wearing black doesn't mean anything in particular.

By saying that her *love life* never actually lived, it is a way of saying that she's never really had a love life. This is a dramatic way of saying that she hasn't had many real dates or relationships.

All of this is meant humorously. It's an example of exaggeration for effect.